# Problem with Pydantic, SQLAlchemy in Fastapi

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

My model Class

```
class History(Base):
    history_id: Mapped[bigint_pk]
    customer_id_1: Mapped[Optional[bigint]]
    customer_role_1: Mapped[Optional[tinyint]] = mapped_column(
        comment=stringify_enum(CustomerTableRole))
    customer_id_2: Mapped[Optional[bigint]]
    customer_role_2: Mapped[Optional[tinyint]] = mapped_column(
        comment=stringify_enum(CustomerTableRole))
    customer_id_3: Mapped[Optional[bigint]]
    customer_role_3: Mapped[Optional[tinyint]] = mapped_column(
        comment=stringify_enum(CustomerTableRole))
    
    customer_1 = relationship(
        'Customer',
        primaryjoin='foreign(History.customer_id_1) '
                    '== Customer.customer_id')
    customer_2 = relationship(
        'Customer',
        primaryjoin='foreign(History.customer_id_2) '
                    '== Customer.customer_id')
    customer_3 = relationship(
        'Customer',
        primaryjoin='foreign(History.customer_id_3) '
                    '== Customer.customer_id')

class Customer(Base):
    customer_id: Mapped[bigint_pk]
    name: Mapped[Optional[varchar_255]]
```

This is my code

```
class CustomerSchema(BaseModel):
    customer_id: int
    name: Optional[str] = None
    customer_role: Optional[int] = None

    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)

class HistoriesSchema(BaseModel):
    history_id: int
    customer_1: Optional[CustomerSchema] = None
    customer_2: Optional[CustomerSchema] = None
    customer_3: Optional[CustomerSchema] = None

    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)
```

How do i set a common name for customer_role_1, customer_role_2, customer_role_3 as customer_role and call it in CustomerSchema. And if customer_1 or customer_2 or customer_3 is Null then don't show it in response

I want response like this. (My example response have cutomer_2:null)

```
{
    'history_id': 1
    'customer_1': {
        'customer_id': 1
        'name': 'customer1'
        'cusomer_role': 1
    },
    'customer_3': {
        'customer_id': 3
        'name': 'customer3'
        'cusomer_role': 3
    }
}
```

Comment: `response_model_exclude_none=True` on the endpoint should behave as you want for your second question: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#use-the-response_model_exclude_unset-parameter (if `History` defines all the fields and you don't want to include other fields that are null). For the first case, using a `@property` and `@computed_field"  that has the logic you want to decide what should be value of the field seems to be the way to go: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/computed_fields/

Comment: thks for reply. How do i use `@property`, `@computed_field` if my class `Customer` don't have customer_role_1, customer_role_2, customer_role_3. I want add customer_role in block each customer

Comment: If you want to include the customer_role object, add it as a relationship so that it gets fetched - you can the include it in your response model as necessary.